# Unable to load OleDbDataReader to DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, oledbdatareader

I am reading data from `MS access 2010` file. I am using `OleDbDataReader` to read the data which is working but when I am unable to load that in `DataTable` .

Code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\My Stuff\AjaxTest & Test porjects\WbsiteWithAccessDataConnectivity\WbsiteWithAccessDataConnectivity\App_Data\Northwind 2010.accdb";
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from Customers", conn))
    {
        using (OleDbDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
        {
            dt.Load(rd); // Unable to load
            rd.Close();
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
return dt;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The question helped me to fix my own issue. I was changing from SqlClient to OleDB in other to accomodate multiple database types so cmd.ExecuteReader() worked with SqlClient but would not load the datatable when I changed to OleDB with adding the CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure if you are getting an error or what is happening with your code but my suggestion would be to add LoadOption and/or errorHandler parameters to find out exactly what is happening.

```
dt.Load(rd,OverwriteChanges); // Unable to load
```

More info here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hsze9wte%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I am not getting any error but `DataTable` is empty. I don't know why?

Comment: Right.  Your code doesn't seem to be trapping any errors either so you may be getting an error without realizing it?  Loading a reader into a datatable should work but you may need to specify a LoadOption to deal with primary keys.   I would also suggest that and error trapping of some sort.  Something is failing somewhere.

Comment: It was my bad. I saw the error count and it was correct. I was missing .DataBind() on dataGrid. Silly mistake!!

Comment: Ah!  Yes.  that would do it.   Glad you got unstuck.